# Algorithm for computing FIRST and FOLLOW sets for context-free grammars

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, ll-grammar

I need an algorithm to computing FIRST and FOLLOW sets for a grammar.

Is there a simple algorithm or simple code for computing these?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The standard algorithm for computing FIRST and FOLLOW sets is discussed in most compiler textbooks and books on parsing algorithms. I would be surprised if you were taking a course where this was covered and had no assigned reading or materials provided on this topic.

I taught a class on compiler construction and have some lecture slides that might be useful here. You might want to check out [slides 303-304 of these slides on LL parsing](http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/lectures/03/Slides03.pdf) for an algorithm that computes FIRST sets and [slide 32 of these slides on LL parsing](http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/lectures/04/Slides04A.pdf) for an algorithm that computes FOLLOW sets.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with [Graphical calculation of first and follow sets of a grammar](https://www.ijser.org/researchpaper/Graphical-Calculation-of-First-and-Follow-sets-of-a-Grammar.pdf) by ASR Murty.

A graphical method has been given to calculate the First and Follow sets of a grammar which is easier to apply for a learner or a student...

This graphical method is applied to the Expression Grammar to find the First and Follow sets and we also check its correctness with the help of derivations.