# I am having problem in finding out the first and follow set of this production rules

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

Here is my grammar:

```
E ⇒ T P 
P ⇒ ε 
P ⇒ l T P 
T ⇒ F Q 
Q ⇒ ε 
Q ⇒ F Q 
F ⇒ ( E ) R 
F ⇒ i R
R ⇒ ε 
R ⇒ * R
```

How can I compute the first and follow sets of these production rules?

Comment: You need to show that you have attempted this problem, otherwise your question will be removed. Please visit the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Here are a couple of questions with resources to find the algorithm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869163/algorithm-for-computing-first-and-follow-sets-for-context-free-grammars and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197332/how-to-find-first-and-follow-sets-of-a-recursive-grammar/29200860#29200860. Search this site and you should find more helpful answers. (You could try a search like `grammar "first set" algorithm`)